# How to add documents to firestore in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm trying to create my first database on firestore, but don't know how when click the button, the addNew() method did'nt run:

Here is the code

```
export default function Login(props: LoginI) {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState<User>();
  const token = useSelector(
    (item: RootState) => item.persistedReducer.token.token
  );
  const dispatch: AppDispatch = useDispatch();
  const {} = props;
  const addNew = () => {
    firestore()
      .collection("Users")
      .add({
        name: "Ada Lovelace",
        age: 30,
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("User added!");
      });
  };
 

  console.log("user token", userInfo?.idToken);
  console.log("token redux", token);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
  
          addNew();  ==>>> not working!!
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Login</Text>
      </Button>
      {userInfo && (
        <Text style={{ color: color.black }}>
          {`Hello ${userInfo.user?.name}`}
        </Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

And it show up this error

[image]

**EDIT**
I follow all the link but the error change to this ( error id2 to id0)

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /todos/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

So please help, i don't know what going on

[image]

Comment: Your database security rules are rejected the write.

Comment: Hey sir, please help, i updated the question and still don't find the way